# How i can get current menu id with multiple occurrence

Tags: menus

I want to get current menu id and i was able to find out some solutions for this like 
[How to get current-menu-item title as variable?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/how-to-get-current-menu-item-title-as-variable/16337#16337)

[How to get current page menu item name instead of full menu item list](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202597/how-to-get-current-page-menu-item-name-instead-of-full-menu-item-list)

I implement this code but it does not work when i have same term or page multiple time in my menu. For Example i have Asia (term) in my menu twice and it always return id of its first occurrence. I check this in source code and both these menu elements (Asia) are assigned with current-menu-item class.  So in this case how i can get correct menu id with multiple occurrence. 
Your help will be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean exactly. If you have Asia in your menu twice, both menu items will have the same `$menu->object_id` which is the page ID. Which "ID" are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I am looking for menu id not for the page id. Menus are assigned with different id's in back end and even on front end i can see different menu id in source code.

Comment: So if I have this correct, you're trying to get the Menu ID by finding a specific item in that menu. Would it be easier to use [`theme_location`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus#Display_Menus_on_Theme) than trying to get menus by items, which could have duplicates in it?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thank you for your suggestion but i want to get id of currently active menu. Above mentioned solutions work perfectly but when i have one term or page multiple time in my menu then it always return id of first occurrence of that particular term or page.

Comment: You want to have this identifier in which action or filter ?

Comment: Right now i am getting menu id using this filter wp_nav_menu_objects as mentioned here in accepted answer. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/how-to-get-current-menu-item-title-as-variable/16337#16337